# Как настроить величину отступа меежду элементами QGridLayout?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlayout, qlabel, qgridlayout

В менеджере компоновки `box - (QGridLayout)` находятся четыре виджета:

- `picture` - скругленное изображение, полученное с помощью класса `RoundArt`;
- три виджета `Qlabel`:

  - `album_title`;
  - `artist`;
  - `year.`

Окно приложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Виджеты `QLabel` расползаются по всему контейнеру так, как хотят. 
Я никак не могу их контролировать и очень хочу это исправить, задав расстояние между виджетами `box`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**L** - расстояние по горизонтали от `picture` до каждого `QLabel`'а. Важно сохранить выравнивание текста по левому краю. Должно быть постоянным и равным `10px`

**H** - расстояние по вертикали между виджетами `QLabel`. Должно быть постоянным и равным `20px`

Пожалуйста, помогите мне расположить виджеты в контейнере `box`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class RoundArt(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, x, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RoundArt, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setFixedSize(x, x)
        self.x = x
        self.radius = 10 

        self.setPicture(picture)

    def setPicture(self, picture):
        target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())
        target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(
            self.x, self.x, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding,
            QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation
        )

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(target)

        painter.end()
        target = None

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        box = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        picture = RoundArt('album.png', 150)
        box.addWidget(picture, 0, 0, 3, 1)

        album_title = QtWidgets.QLabel('Album Title')
        box.addWidget(album_title, 0, 1)

        artist = QtWidgets.QLabel('Artist')
        box.addWidget(artist, 1, 1)

        year = QtWidgets.QLabel('2001')
        box.addWidget(year, 2, 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще воспользоваться комбинацией `Layout-ов`. Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class RoundArt(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, x, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RoundArt, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setFixedSize(x, x)
        self.x = x
        self.radius = 10 
        self.setPicture(picture)

    def setPicture(self, picture):
        target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())
        target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(
            self.x, self.x, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding,
            QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation
        )
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(target)
        painter.end()
        target = None

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

#        box = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        picture = RoundArt('head3.png', 150)
        box_V = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        box_V.addWidget(picture)
        box_V.addStretch(1)
        box.addLayout(box_V)
        box.addSpacing(10)

        box_V = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        album_title = QtWidgets.QLabel('Album Title')
        album_title.setFixedHeight(30)
#        box.addWidget(album_title, 0, 1)
        box_V.addSpacing(10)
        box_V.addWidget(album_title)
        box_V.addSpacing(20)

        artist = QtWidgets.QLabel('Artist')
        artist.setFixedHeight(30)
#        box.addWidget(artist, 1, 1)
        box_V.addWidget(artist)
        box_V.addSpacing(20)

        year = QtWidgets.QLabel('2001')
        year.setFixedHeight(30)
#        box.addWidget(year, 2, 1)
        box_V.addWidget(year)
        box_V.addSpacing(10)
        box_V.addStretch(1)

        box.addLayout(box_V)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]